# Links inside of floated LI wrapping in Chrome

Tags: html, css, webkit

So, I have the following HTML structure:

```
<div id="category-filter">
    <div class="column full">
        <ul class="float-clear" id="category-filter">
            <li><a href="/learn" data-category_id="">All Categories</a></li>
            <li><a href="/learn/C3" data-category_id="3">Educator Workshops</a></li>
            <li><a href="/learn/C1" data-category_id="1">Exhibitions</a></li>
            <li><a href="/learn/C5" data-category_id="5">Family Activities</a></li>
            <li><a href="/learn/C4" data-category_id="4">Films</a></li>
            <li><a href="/learn/C6" data-category_id="6">Lectures + Gallery Talks</a></li>
            <li><a href="/learn/C8" data-category_id="8">Music</a></li>
            <li><a href="/learn/C9" data-category_id="9">Other Activities</a></li>
            <li><a href="/learn/C7" data-category_id="7">Tours</a></li>
            <li><a href="/learn/C2" data-category_id="2">Workshops</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

Which, after styling produces the following in Firefox:

[image]

However, in Webkit, the link text wraps:

[image]

The `LI` tags are floated left and should grow with the size of anchor inside them and then wrap as needed inside the container which has a width set. Any ideas why the links are wrapping in Webkit?

Comment: If you change the div to a li, you'll have valid html.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add white-space:nowrap; to the links to avoid break line.
And `<ul>` element must only contain `<li>`.

Comment: Ha! That UL should've been a div. I guess that was the result of a late night. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 3):

It's guesswork without seeing your CSS, but try this:

```
#category-filter a {
    white-space: nowrap
}
```

That should stop the text from wrapping.

---

And as already mentioned, it's invalid to have a `div` as a direct child of a `ul`. You should change it to `<li class="column full">`. You might also have to adjust some of the selectors in your CSS.