# Why do floated items in an li wrap in chrome at other zoom levels?

Tags: css, html, layout, css-float

I have a `ul` with `li`s inside that I'm using as a tab list.  The `li`s have an image and some text inside of them.  For some reason, in chrome, the text doesn't appear on the same line as the image, but wraps to the next line.

I can't understand why this would happen, shouldn't the li expand to give enough space to fit both the image and the text?  This problem doesn't happen on Firefox or IE.  Testing with Chrome 22, Firefox 16 and IE 9 on Windows 7.

[image: firefox example]
[image: chrome example]

[See this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/NypvL/1/) to see the markup (extracted from a longer page - also not the real icons).

It sounds [similar to this problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6145422/links-inside-of-floated-li-wrapping-in-chrome), but the `nowrap` trick didn't work for me.

**Update:**  I just realized I had a different zoom level set, 144%.  At some zoom levels the issue happens, and others it does not.  I guess it might have something to do with the ems for some sizes, and px for others?  I still don't get why this would happen though, shouldn't it still get the proper amount of room?

Comment: Different elements displaying differently between browsers is usually due to default browser CSS. Add a reset before you apply your own CSS and it should fix the issues you're experiencing. http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/

Comment: Which version of Chrome? I'm looking at your fiddle in the latest Chrome for mac, and it looks fine.

Comment: Chrome 22.  I'm using the html5 boilerplate and its resets, which I didn't copy into the fiddle.

Comment: OK, I just did a check on a Linux box and didn't see the problem with chrome.  Realized on Win my default zoom level is 144%.  So it's something to do with that, maybe it's miscalculating the size?

Answer (score 0):

Set a minimum width on the header. You also have the issue if you reduce the browser size. Figure out how small it can go before it starts to stack and set the min-width on the header to that size, that fixes it if the browser is zoomed too.

Comment: I get that when the browser is too small the floats would wrap.  But when there is plenty of space, it doesn't make sense to be that it would wrap.  I wanted to avoid specifying a size, but I guess I will have to

Comment: It's wrapping in some browsers and not others because of different default CSS. Check out a reset or normalize for your site before applying your regular CSS if you want all browsers to behave the same when it comes to styling. It's actually good practice even if you aren't having any issues to apply one or the other.

Comment: As I said before, it is NOT due to the lack of reset.  I didn't bother to include the reset in the example because it didn't make much difference.

You can see in this version where I included my reset it still has the same problem on windows http://jsfiddle.net/NypvL/3/ at 110% and 144% zoom.

I'm thinking this is a windows chrome bug, because it doesn't happen on my mac at the same zoom levels.

Comment: Sorry didn't reread the whole thing when I answered this morning. Regardless I still think given the design that it actually NEEDS a specified width, either that or media queries to make the layout not break when the browser is reduced too far.